# Insert and select in one query

Tags: c#, sql

I have a query

```
 insert into carsdescription
 (description,idCar) 
 value (@description,@idCar)
 where idCar=@idCar;
 select nameOfCar
 from Cars 
 where idCar=@idCar";
```

How to in one sqlCommand execute this??

```
using(SqlConnection conn=new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    using(sqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Parameteres, conn etc... //this is a peanut

        // your proposition    
    }
}
```

table schema:

Carsdescription :

```
 ID (PK, int, autoincrement)
idcar(FK, int)
Description(varchar)
```

Cars

```
Id(int, PK, autoincrement)
Name(nvarchar(255)
```

Comment: If that's a peanut, what have I been snacking on?

Comment: Please show your table schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. Not in a single statement. Why do you even want to?? What's your idea, or your requirement??

You have to use a `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` call first to insert the new data, and then you need a second call using `cmd.ExecuteReader` or filling a DataTable using the SqlDataAdapter to retrieve the data again.

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();

    string cmdInsert = "insert into carsdescription(description) value (@description)";

    using(sqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdInsert, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", description);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    string selectStmt = "select nameOfCar from dbo.Cars where idCar = @idCar";

    using(sqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(selectStmt, conn))
    {
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idCar", idCar);

        string resultValue = cmd2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    }

    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: why not? i am sure it is possible!

Comment: @Jacob G: sorry, actually, **you** are wrong - see my comment to your answer. Your answer is **NOT** one statement

Comment: This is not necessarily a fruitful avenue of discussion (http://xkcd.com/386/) however, the original questioner was asking about a single sqlcommand.

Comment: @Jacob G: ok, granted - you could interpret the OP's question as how to do these two steps in one SqlCommand - then your answer is right on. I was interpreting it as how to do this in one single T-SQL statement, and that isn't possible

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to copy data from one table to another?

Something like

```
INSERT INTO CarsDescription (description)
    SELECT nameOfCar
        FROM Cars
        WHERE idCar = @idCar
```

That will copy all the 'nameOfCar' values into the CarsDescription table.  If you don't want duplicates change the *SELECT* to *SELECT DISTINCT*

Comment: that's one possibility - the original question isn't quite clear on this, really.

Comment: @marc_s, yeah, I know... I wasn't sure if he was trying to return the rows that were just inserted, or trying to insert from a select.

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into carsdescription (description) value (@description) where idCar=@idCar;
```

INSERT ... WHERE ??

(not that I know what you're actually trying to do, but that query won't work in the first place)

Comment: I think his comment was referring to the fact that a Where Clause on an Insert Statement is nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

Create a stored procedure that takes Description and IDCar as parameters and returns either a scalar NameOfCar or else a result set from the Cars table.  You can then call that stored procedure with a single command from your C# code.

Answer (score 2):

This is perfectly valid to execute in a single call.  It might not be recommended, but it is possible.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=JunkBox;Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO JunkSO(Id, Name) VALUES(@Id, @Description)  SELECT * FROM JunkSO", conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", 10);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", "TestDescription");
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (rd.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (rd.Read())
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(rd[0].ToString() + "  " + rd[1].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = your_query;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@description", description));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@idCar", idCar));
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            //reader here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I also found one way, I know that it's messy but I am also a beginner so I did as follows for myself.

```
SqlConnection add = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sismanager"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand additem = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Godown(Gname, Gstock) VALUES(@Gname, @Gstock)", add);
        additem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gname", textBox1.Text.Trim());
        additem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gstock", textBox2.Text.Trim());
        try
        {               
            add.Open();
            additem.ExecuteNonQuery();              
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            add.Close();

            dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
            SqlConnection setcon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sismanager"].ConnectionString);
            using (SqlCommand getdata = new SqlCommand("SELECT Gid, Gname, Gstock FROM Godown ORDER BY Gname ASC", setcon))
            {
                setcon.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(getdata);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Gname";
                    comboBox1.ValueMember = "Gid";
                    comboBox1.DataSource = dt;

                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Item Id";
                    dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Item";
                    dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Item Stock";

                    DataGridViewButtonColumn deletebtn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
                    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(deletebtn);
                    deletebtn.HeaderText = "Remove";
                    deletebtn.Text = "Remove";
                    deletebtn.Name = "Dbtn";
                    deletebtn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No Stock Items to Show", "Stock Details", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }
        }
```

However this answer is irrelevant to your question, but I have tried my own solution.